# Snapping Pose Bones to Vertex 90 degrees Off

Tags: coordinates, snapping, pose-mode

I'm trying to snap the tail of a pose bone to a vertex in another mesh.  When I hit R or G to start moving the bone, it snaps just fine, but rotates the bone approximately 90 degrees away from the point it's snapping to.  I would like the dotted line it's using for snapping to go from the head to the tail of the bone.

Pre-snap
[image: Pre Snap]

During snap
[image: Snap 90 degrees off]

Desired snap (simulated by holding "Ctrl" while rotating)
[image: Desired]

I'm sure this is a coordinate system feature, just not sure how to work with it.